# Two separate login pages in Symfony 2

Tags: authentication, symfony

I'm trying to figure out how to have two separate login pages: a default login for the `.com` page and one for specific users, for example for the route `/special`.

Is this easily possible with in one SF2 project?

UPDATE:

I have the following configuration in my firewall (I'm using fosub)

```
providers:
    custom:
        id: ib.user_provider
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_manager
    my_fos_facebook_provider:
        id: my.facebook.user

firewalls:
    special:
        pattern: ^/special
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            login_path: /special/login
            check_path: /special/login_check
            use_referer: false
            default_target_path: /special
            success_handler: ib.login_handler
            provider: custom
    main:
        pattern: ^/.*
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login_check
            use_referer: false
            default_target_path: /
            provider: custom
        fos_facebook:
            always_use_default_target_path: true
            app_url: "http://apps.facebook.com/%facebook_app_id%/"
            server_url: "http://aw.com/aw/web/app_dev.php/"
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login_check/facebook
            default_target_path: /checkFB
            success_handler: facebook_auth_success_handler
            provider: my_fos_facebook_provider
        logout:
            #handlers: ["fos_facebook.logout_handler"]
            target: /
        anonymous:    ~
```

In the ib.login_handler I have the following:

```
public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request,TokenInterface $token)
{
    if ($this->security->isGranted('ROLE_CATEGORIZER'))
    {
        $response = new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('MyCoBundle_mailAdmin_index'));
    }


    return $response;
}
```

With this configuration if I go to mydomain.com/special  I get the following error: Fehler: Umleitungsfehler  (in english: Error: Redirection error)

UPDATE:

in chrome I get: No route found for "GET /special/login"

```
404 Not Found - NotFoundHttpException
1 linked Exception: ResourceNotFoundException »
```

I don't have a special route for this login path. What I want to achieve is just, that a special user has only access to pages under the path / special.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's possible, you can define many protected zones => many firewalls.

Let's see this ***app/config/security.yml*** configuration to know how :

```
firewalls:

    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    special_area:
        pattern:  ^/special
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            check_path: /special/login_check
            login_path: /special/login
        logout:
            path:   /special/logout
            target: /

    general_area:
        pattern:  ^
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            check_path: /login_check
            login_path: /login
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /


access_control:
    - { path: ^/_internal, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ip: 127.0.0.1 }

    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/special/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Beware that **special_area** must be defined above **genereal_area** because general_area's pattern matches every other ones...

What you must add in your bundle routing.yml :

```
_security_login_special:
    pattern:  /special/login
    defaults: { _controller: FOSUserBundle:Security:login }

_security_check_special:
    pattern:  /special/login_check

_security_logout_special:
    pattern:  /special/logout
```

And you have to add another role for general_area, so you need to override FOSUserManager and make it add this supplementary role on user loading... (More information here : https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/1.2.0/Resources/doc/user_manager.md)

Comment: Hi, thanks for you post. unfortunately i'mg getting an error wen trying the above setup. maybe i should post my firewall config above.

Comment: Hi, please post the whole error message ;) in english, my german has been drawned during Oktoberfet in Munich ;) Are /login and /special/login corresponding to any route in your routing ?

Comment: What i want to achieve in the end is just, that one user with a special role can see only special pages under /special, but should not be able to see other pages for the default user. I'll paste the error message above.

Comment: So, the error comes from you didn't define /special/login pattern in your routing configuration. You must do it first.

Comment: Then, right access are defined in the access_control part. You must define a ROLE for general_area (that special users won't get), and a ROLE_SPECIAL, that only special users will get)...

Comment: But how to combine that with FOSUB ? In general the default user is getting the ROLE_USER role... so my special user will have ROLE_USER, and ROLE_SPECIAl, right? and what should i add to the /special/login pattern? i want FOSUB to handle the login

Comment: Don't add anything to the pattern, jus declare the route in your routing (i've updated my answer).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10128/discussion-between-ramo-and-pece)

Comment: FOSUserBundle:Security:login is this a real path in the bundle? I can't find it there.

Comment: It does exist. It's referenceed by FOSUserBundle routing [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/routing/security.xml) and the Controller itself is [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Controller/SecurityController.php). No chat, i'm leaving my work place...