# Two different login forms in Symfony 2

Tags: symfony

### Background

According to the Symfony documentation the login form needs to be specified on the security.yml file, also hes login_check path. Until now my app is working fine, users tries to access a secure page (mysite.com/edit/123) next if they are not logged they will be redirected to /login and after they login they will be redericted again to the original intended path (/edit/123).

Similar question: [Two separate login pages in Symfony 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166081/two-separate-login-pages-in-symfony-2)

### Problem

The problem now is, i need a different login form, lets say /minimal_login, i need to include that on the security.yml but the only way i know is creating a different firewall, and as i saw on the documentation this creates a separate identification scheme, so i suppose users logged by differents firewall can not share the same secured pages, and thats not what i want.

### What is need

If the user tries to access any secure page but /popup they will be redirected to /login, BUT if they tries to access /popup (and they are not logged) they will be redirected to /minimal_login. And no matter how the user logs into my app, they will always share the same access, i mean, if they log in using /login or /minimal_login they can access the same pages.

---

### My secuity.yml

```
jms_security_extra:
    secure_all_services: false
    expressions: true

security:
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH ]

    providers:
        main:
            entity: {class: Done\PunctisBundle\Entity\User, property: username}

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            remember_me:
                key: %secret%
                lifetime: 3600
                path: /
                domain: ~
            pattern: ^/
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path: /login
                check_path: /login_check
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /


    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/signup, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/verification, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/popup/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/ajax/track, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/ajax/socialbox, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }

    encoders:
        Done\PunctisBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm:   md5
            iterations: 1
            encode_as_base64: false
```

Comment: Are you using FOSUserBundle, or?

Comment: Im using the default system

Comment: I think it's probably best to not have multiple login URLs for the same application, as it would double the amount of work if something should change(DRY).  Instead, why not render the appropriate template based on the URL in your login controller?

Answer (score 6):

I faced a similar problem and I solved using the `firewall context` configuration.

```
firewalls:
    somename:
        # ...
        context: my_context
    othername:
        # ...
        context: my_context
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#firewall-context

Comment: Good catch. I didn't think of this option